# Sinonjs Cannot read property 'quoteStrings' of undefined

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, sinon

Sinon is giving me some fun error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'quoteStrings' of undefined
    at ascii (http://localhost:3500/assets/sinon.js?body=1:164:36)
    at Function.array (http://localhost:3500/assets/sinon.js?body=1:207:25)
    at Object.ascii (http://localhost:3500/assets/sinon.js?body=1:179:26)
    at Object.format (http://localhost:3500/assets/sinon.js?body=1:594:36)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3500/assets/sinon.js?body=1:1065:43)
    at Function.toString (http://localhost:3500/assets/sinon.js?body=1:1744:54)
    at Function.verify (http://localhost:3500/assets/sinon.js?body=1:1761:49)
    at Context.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3500/assets/views/myview_spec.js?body=1:29:21)
    at Test.run (http://localhost:3500/assets/mocha.js:3322:32)
    at Runner.runTest (http://localhost:3500/assets/mocha.js:3630:10)
```

Here's the test that causes it:

```
    beforeEach ->
      # make a fake collection object
      collection =
        each: ->


      @subject = new App.Views.TaskList collection: collection
      @sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create()

    it 'renders each task in the collection', ->

      task = ['task model']
      @sandbox.stub(@subject.collection, 'each').yields task

      mock = @sandbox.mock(@subject).expects('renderTask')
                                    .withExactArgs(task, skipLayout: true)
      @subject.render()
      mock.verify()
```

And the code under test:

```
 render: =>
    @collection.each (task) =>
      @renderTask task

    this
```

#### UPDATE:

Turns out that when I update the code to pass the test I don't get the error:

```
 render: =>
    @collection.each (task) =>
      @renderTask task, skipLayout: true

    this
```

So it must have something to do with the sinon.js expectation failure. Probably a sinon.js bug.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the exact same bug in my code. Couldn't figure out the exact source to submit an upstream patch so I worked around using stubs:

```
mock = @sandbox.stub collection, 'renderTask'

@subject.render()

mock.callCount.should.equal 1
mock.calledWith.should.equal task, skipLayOut: true
```

Ugly but it works. The exact syntax for the assertions will be different based on your framework; I'm using chai in the example.

Comment: This has been my conclusion as well. The sinon mocks add nicer failure output, but once you get more than a single example they end up being more trouble than they're worth. Which has led me to use the stub + callCount approach.